# how to refresh combobox items in vb .net

Tags: refresh

how to refresh combobox items in vb .net

Comment: Wat do you mean with refresh? 
Is it WinForms or Web?

When you add or remove items, the list is automatically updated.

Comment: I usually have a sub that clears all the combo, like `combox.items.clear` and then i add all the items again if i have to add manually an item.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about a comboBox on a WinForm that's been assigned to a list of objects using the datasource property, I found that you must nullify the datasource setting and re-assign it every time your list changes.

i.e.

```
  attendanceDataFiles.DataSource = Nothing
  attendanceDataFiles.DataSource = myFileList.files
  attendanceDataFiles.DisplayMember = "displayName"
  attendanceDataFiles.ValueMember = "fileName"
```

Comment: +1 as the tip about temporarily setting to Nothing helped me with some odd behaviour with the DevComponents suite

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to refresh combo box items if your combo box's content is from MySql Database. You can customize your results in the query.

```
        comboboxname.Items.clear() 'empty combo box content first

        query = "select code, description from tbl_mode_of_payment where cat = 'LICENSE'" 'mysql query that retrieves payment code and its description based on category
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read
            comboboxname.Items.Add(reader.GetString("code") + " - " + reader.GetString("description"))  'add results into the combo box
        End While
        con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Textbox1.Item.Clear() 
then 
call.item_tb()

Answer (score 0):

I have to refresh a combobox after another form adds new items into the database table.  I also use a datasource for the combobox.  This is what I have done and it works well.

```
 Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()
 Dim dt_Institutions As DataTable

 '~~ The connection is a public OleDbConnection at the head of the form class 
 cmd.Connection = conn
 conn.Open()

 '~~ The control already has been assigned a datasource.  Instead of creating
 '   new one, I reuse the old one.  It must first be cleared of the old data
 dt_Institutions = cb_Institutions.DataSource
 dt_Institutions.Clear()

 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Institutions.InstitutionID, " &
                   "       Institutions.Institution " &
                   "  FROM Institutions " &
                   " ORDER BY Institutions.Institution"
 
 '~~ While this is not necessary, if you have a large amount of data beging 
 '   filled in, the combobox control will want to sort and organize it with
 '   each add.  This prevents that from happening (and speeding up the code)
 dt_Institutions.BeginLoadData()

 '~~ Looping through the data from the SELECT statement and filling up the
 '   the recycled dataset
 Using rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
     While rdr.Read()
         dt_Institutions.Rows.Add({rdr("InstitutionID"), rdr("Institution").ToString})
     End While
 End Using

 '~~ Let the combobox take back over and organize itself only after all the
 '   data has been retrieved
 dt_Institutions.EndLoadData()

 cb_Institutions.SelectedIndex = -1

 conn.Close()
```

I have used this with an MS-Access database and coded in VS 2022.  The procedure is called from another form that has added a new record (in this case a new institution).